# how to exclude a sub directory from cmake file

Tags: cmake

I am using cmake and in dir i have lot of sub-dir something like this

main_dir

```
 - sub_dir_a
 - sub_dir_b
 - sub_dir_c
    .
    .
 - sub_dir_z
```

Lets say i need to include all sub-dir except "sub_dir_z"
and in cmake I use the command

```
target_include_directories
```

Instead of including every seperate sub-dir and leaving out "sub_dir_z",
is there any command such that i simply do
target_include_directories on "main_dir" and exclude "sub_dir_z"

Answer (score 3):

There is no command for it, afaik. But you can implement it yourself pretty easily by combining other commands. Something like this:

```
file(GLOB SUB_FOLDERS LIST_DIRECTORIES true "*")
list(FILTER SUB_FOLDERS EXCLUDE REGEX "sub_dir_z")
target_include_directories(YourTarget PRIVATE ${SUB_FOLDERS})
```